# ObservableCollection addings items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF application I have an Observable Collection of `Functions`

```
private ObservableCollection<Function> functions = new ObservableCollection<Function>();
```

I wrote a command for a button to add new functions to the collection:
In this case I am adding a polynomial function.

```
public ICommand AddPolyFuncCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(obj =>
        {
            Function newPolyFunc = new PolyFunction(this.Coefficients);
            functions.Add(newPolyFunc);
            CalculatePoints();
        });
    }
}
```

However, if I keep adding more functions, all of the latest functions in the collection are overwritten with the function I want to add. For example I have 3 entries, but the functions are all the same (they should be different).

For example, I create a first function. After that I want to add another different function to the collection.
It lets me create the "newPolyFunc" properly but if I take a look at the `FunctionsCollection` at runtime the first value is already overwritten with the function.

```
public ICommand AddTrigoFuncCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(obj =>
            {
                this.functions.Add(newTrigoFunc);
                CalculatePoints();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but your code should be functions.Add(newPolyFunc)

Comment: That didn't solve it.

Comment: I didn't think it would but your code snippet was syntactically incorrect - just pointing that out

Comment: Does the first item get overwritten immediately after the call to function.Add() ?

Comment: It actually happens before that. When I stop the debugger before the function.Add(), the first entry is already overwritten. I know, this is very strange. Then, after the .Add(), there are 2 entries of the same function.

Comment: There is some other code causing the problem, you need to spend some time debugging all the pieces that interact with your collection.

Comment: Assuming `this.Coefficients` is an `ObservableCollection`, you give the new `Function` a reference to the `Coefficients`. You may want to pass a deep copy instead of a reference like this `ObservableCollection<double> newCoefficients = new ObservableCollection<double>(Coefficients.Select(c => c));`

Comment: @LittleBit You are a genius! Thank you very much.

Comment: No Problem, should i post it as answer and explain it a little further?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's on you. Could you just quickly explain me how I can make a copy of the `newTrigoFunc` (It's from the type `TrigoFunction`). I added the code on top. Here I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `Function newPolyFunc = new PolyFunction(this.Coefficients);` you pass the Reference of the `Coefficents` and not a new set of Coefficients. You could use LINQ to create a deep copy of the Coefficients or create an empty set and pass them like this:

```
//Create deep copy and pass them
ObservableCollection<double> newCoefficients = new ObservableCollection<double>(Coefficients.Select(c => c));

//Create empty set
ObservableCollection<double> newCoefficients = new ObservableCollection<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(0d, Amount/Grade));
```

Important: When you pass a reference you pass a pointer to the instance/object and not a clone/copy. Always be aware if its a reference or value type. For example the `newTrigoFunc` is an instance and is passed as reference. So the `this.functions` has now the same reference saved 2 times and not to different instances/objects. When you want to add a new object/instance i suggest you to create a new one with the Constructor like this

```
//Add new object/instance
this.functions.Add(new TrigonometricFunctionClass(parameters?));
```